# How do you login, check your user account and execute queries as a specific user in Cassandra?

Tags: security, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

Once Cassandra has user accounts set up, how do you login as one of them? Alternatively how do I execute queries as a specific user?

Also, how do you check what user account you are logged in as?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to run the console as a certain user you do:

```
cqlsh -u YOUR_USERNAME -p YOUR_PASSWORD
```

according to the following video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CAQyCdsNW-Q&list=PL6yjrg6fu0Ot4qz3ydBmmqbENe02HqNLV&index=71

Comment: Is there a way to login to the keyspace you want too at the same time?

Comment: I agree, though I wrote everything I know. Feel free to suggest how I can make my answer better if you know information that I did not provide (also, my answer was put before your bounty was set on).